# Convert a number from base A to base B

Tags: c++, radix

Given two positive integers A and B and a string S of size N, denoting a number in base A, the task is to convert the given string S from base A to base B.

Example:

"25"
**Base A :** 6
**Base B :** 8
**Expected Result :** 21

Explanation:
The Number 25 is represented in base 6 format. The goal is to convert it to base 8 which in this case is 21.

Comment: You what? A number is just a number. We like to use base 10 when displaying the number.

Comment: A number's base only comes into play when you convert it to a string representation, such as when you display it. Otherwise, numeric types just contain a value. An `int` doesn't have a base.

Comment: What have you try so far?

Comment: *as fast as possible* -- This type of request. "as fast as possible", is really meaningless.  If someone comes up with one method, there will be someone else that comes up with something that runs infinitesimally faster.

Comment: When asking for faster algorithms, the response is always "please tell us about your performance problem". If you don't have one, then it's probably premature optimization. I suggest writing any algorithm first, then worry about optimizing it later.

Comment: My man.. I said that I don't even have a solution for my problem, how should I write an algorithm first? If you want a garbage algorithm that does nothing tell me.. .

Answer (score 2):

1. divide the number by base.
2. write down the remainder.
3. repeat the process with the integer part of the division.
4. stop when you reach zero.
5. the remainders in reverse order give you the digits in base

With an array with the chars that corresponds to the base in order, base 32 should be like:

`char digits[32] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv";`

I would use recursivity, but its up to you. When you divide, use the remainder in the array, so if the remainder is 12 for example, you will have the `'c'` char.

If you have a string instead of a number for the original number, you can use `string[i]-'a'+10` in the letters to obtain the corresponding number.

Answer (score -2):

use itoa

```
char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );
```

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

Comment: `itoa` is not a function from the standard library and is likely to be unavailable.

Comment: @Kaznov In C++17 there's [std::to_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) which does require you to provide your own char buffer but is a standard library function.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes, and I think it should be the answer to this question

Comment: <cstdlib> not in the standard library, who knew?

Comment: @njamescouk Quoting the website: "This function is not defined in ANSI-C and is not part of C++, but is supported by some compilers"